# Как внести значение переменной в функцию?

Tags: javascript

Как из prompt(); занести значение в функцию?
Что я делаю не так?

```
        var = square;
        square = prompt("укажите число");

        function square(num1) {
        var itog = num1**2;
            document.write("квадрат числа " + num1 + " равен: " + itog);
    }
```

Comment: Вот у вас и переменная называется `square` и функция называется `square`. Вы не запутались еще что где?

Answer (score 2):

Первое - `var = square;` это не имеющая никакого смысла строка кода.

Второе - чтобы не путаться где у вас что - называйте переменные и функции **по-разному**.

```js
var input_number = prompt("укажите число");
square(input_number);

function square(num1) {
    var itog = num1**2;
    document.write("квадрат числа " + num1 + " равен: " + itog);
}
```